# ReferenceError: User is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I've got an error while i try to auth via vkontakte (vk.com) (passport-vkontakte)
**Error:** *ReferenceError: User is not defined*
Here is my **auth.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport'), VKontakteStrategy = require('passport-vkontakte').Strategy;
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Auth');
});

passport.use(new VKontakteStrategy({
        clientID:     000, // VK.com docs call it 'API ID'
        clientSecret: '***',
        callbackURL:  "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/vkontakte/callback"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        User.findOrCreate({ vkontakteId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
            return done(err, user);
        });
    }
));

router.get('/vkontakte',
    passport.authenticate('vkontakte'),
    function(req, res){
        // The request will be redirected to vk.com for authentication, so
        // this function will not be called.
    });

router.get('/vkontakte/callback',
    passport.authenticate('vkontakte', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    function(req, res) {
        // Successful authentication, redirect home.
        var User = req.User;
        res.redirect('/');
    });

router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});
module.exports = router;
```

Express ver: 4

Answer (score 3):

## Define User Model

### Mongoose or Mongoskin Example

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var BlogPost = new Schema({
    author    : ObjectId
  , title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
});

var Post = mongoose.model('ModelName', BlogPost);

Post.findOrCreate({ id: QUERY }, function (err, docs) {

});
```

You need to create a model so your strategy can interact with your application properly. In your case, this model will be for users so it is appropriately named `User` as an entity.

#### Boilerplate Code to Get You Started

This code was added from the strategy developers to get you started.

```
User.findOrCreate({ vkontakteId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
    return done(err, user);
});
```

It's the same concept, hope this clears things up.